# Decrease Progress bar depending of a integer value in java

Tags: java, progress-bar, awt

I'm programming a game in Java, I wonder if there is any way that a progress bar will decrease depending on a number of life entered by the user. For example if the number of lives read from the input is 3, then every time the monster touch the protagonist, the life of the character is decremented of the progress bar in 1/3 ".

Comment: Set the percentage of the bar to the percentage of the characters health? So set completion to 2/3 to get what you want.

Comment: How are you displaying the progress bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wonder if there is any way that a progress bar will decrease
>   depending on a number of life entered by the user.

Assuming you are already drawing the progress bar, how about passing the amount of lives entered by the user to the function you use to draw the progress bar. With this you will be able to draw the progress bar at a smaller size. This way would allow handling it in the function:

```
 int userInputLives; //With this variable containing the user input.
 DrawProgressBar(0,400,userInputLives); //Taking x1, y1, User input.
```

You could also do something like this (Assuming you draw the progress bar like this):

```
 int userInputLives; //With this variable containing the users input.
 DrawProgressBar(0,400,0+(userInputLives),400); //Taking x1, y1, x2, y2.
```